# My meanjs Application is not getting started in offline mode?

Tags: node.js, offline, meanjs

I have installed all the prerequisites for a mean application(MEAN) as described in [Meanjs Official website](http://meanjs.org)

I want you to look at this particular error I am getting and that too when I am offline.
But it does work  well when I am connected to internet.
Help me Try looking at the error below:

```
Could not connect to MongoDB!
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
C:\Users\ASHOK\Downloads\meanjs-mean-88a89f2\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:186
      throw err;
            ^
Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASHOK\Downloads\meanjs-mean-88a89f2\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:555
:25)
at emit (events.js:118:17)
at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASHOK\Downloads\meanjs-mean-88a89f2\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_po
ol.js:156:15)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASHOK\Downloads\meanjs-mean-88a89f2\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.
js:534:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at net.js:950:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start mongodb: try typing `mongod` into the terminal

Comment: Yes i did use `mongod`

Comment: See the main issue is when i am offline means i am not connected to internet this error shows up..

Comment: please i need help 
Do you have any idea..
How did you installed mongo ...any different procedure